# Get every round hour from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data stored in Firestore, the data add to Firestore every second, so in 24 hours I have 1440 documents (24 * 60), I want to fetch only round hour from the Firestore for show it on a Graph, how can I get only round hour from Firestore?

Comment: Are you trying to get the data separately for each full hour, like get data where time between 1:00pm and 2:00pm? And it should return you those 60 records for this hour?

Comment: No.. i'm trying to get only the 1:00pm and 2:00pm (3:00pm etc..) date

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will have to store the firestore documents with a timestamp property and then query the documents with the timestamp value which gives a rounded hour using [DateTime](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.2/dart-core/DateTime-class.html) and [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) APIs of flutter.

Once you've got a timestamp back from Firestore, something like :
Timestamp(seconds=1560523991, nanoseconds=286000000)

You can get only rounded hour from the timestamp value using 2 ways :

You need to parse it into an object of type DateTime:

```
DateTime myDateTime = (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp']).toDate(); // prints 2020-05-09 15:27:04.074
```

This will return your Firestore timestamp in the dart's DateTime format. In order to convert your DateTime object you can use DateFormat class from the [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package. You can use your obtained DateTime object to get the format of your choice like this:

**Possible Solution 1 :**

```
DateFormat.Hm().format(myDateTime); //prints 15.27
```

So the query should look for documents with:
`DateFormat.m().format(myDateTime) to be “00”` as

```
DateFormat.m() returns minutes and if minutes == 00 then the timestamp is rounded to the nearest hour.
```

**Possible Solution 2** :

Convert timestamp into timestring using :

```
Let TimeString = snapshot.data.documents[index].data['timestamp']).toDate().toString() // prints ‘2019-12-28 18:48:48.364’

Let time = TimeString.split(“ “)[1] // prints 18:48:48.364

To check if the minutes is “00” :
if  time.substring(3,5) == “00”, then it's a rounded hour. //here it is 48
```

You will have to put these timestamp conversion logics and then query as I mentioned for the rounded hour timestamp. There are no readymade available functions/methods to get the firestore documents with rounded hours.

Comment: My question was only about get the timestamp data from firebase, every round hours, and your answer doesn't answer that..

Comment: [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp#public-constructors) object in firebase is represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time. You will have to use DateFormat methods/toDate()/toString()/DateTime methods to convert it into Date time format. I don't think we have an inbuilt method for getting rounded hours directly from firebase timestamp. So I provided an alternate solution to give you an idea how you can do the conversions. Try to implement this and come back with questions if any.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore supports ["IN" Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).

Store as [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp), and try with following

```
const roundhour1 = new Date('2021-10-01T01:00:00.000z');
const roundhour2 = new Date('2021-10-01T02:00:00.000z');
```

And then write the query like below:

```
database.collection("collectionName").where("fieldName", "in", ["roundhour1", "roundhour2"]);
```

You can have up to 10 values (roundhourX) to check "IN" of, so need to fire 3 queries to get all 24 hours data.